# Perl: Hash values change after returning from a subroutine

Tags: perl, hash, return-value, subroutine

I'm working with hashes in perl, but don't understand why the hash value changes in the following:

```
use strict;

sub test
{
    my ($value_ref) = @_;
    my %value = %$value_ref;
    $value{'abc'}{'xyz'} = 1;
}

my %hash;
$hash{'abc'}{'xyz'} = 0;
test (\%hash);
print "$hash{'abc'}{'xyz'}\n";
```

The above returns 1, why doesn't it return 0 like this it does here?

```
use strict;

sub test
{
    my ($value_ref) = @_;
    my %value = %$value_ref;
    $value{'abc'} = 1;
}

my %hash;
$hash{'abc'} = 0;
test (\%hash);
print "$hash{'abc'}\n";
```

I imagine it has to do with how I'm passing in %hash. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting incorrect results because when you make your *copy* of the hash using `my %value = %$value_ref;` you are only getting the top-level keys. The second level, with the key `'xyz'`, is the one where value is actually stored so any changes to that *reference* are carried over. You are performing a *shallow* copy when you need a *deep* copy.

Luckily there is a CPAN module for that!

```
use strict;
use Storable qw(dclone);

sub test
{
    my ($value_ref) = @_;
    my %value = %{ dclone($value_ref) };
    $value{'abc'}{'xyz'} = 1;
}

my %hash;
$hash{'abc'}{'xyz'} = 0;
test (\%hash);
print "$hash{'abc'}{'xyz'}\n"; # prints 0
```

Comment: also: [Data::Clone](http://p3rl.org/Data::Clone), [Clone](http://p3rl.org/Clone), [Clone::PP](http://p3rl.org/Clone::PP), [Data::Walk::Clone](http://p3rl.org/Data::Walk::Clone)

Comment: How do I make the top-level keys to be reference too?

Answer (score 3):

This is because the "second level" of your hash (IOW: the value for key 'abc') is itself a hash reference.  While you're copying the contents of the hash referenced by `$value_ref` in your assignment:

```
my %value = %$value_ref;
```

...this is only doing a "shallow" copy.

When you modify the value for key 'xyz', you're modifying the same hash that is in the original structure passed to the sub.